# iOS Keyboard Colour Changes - keyboardAppearance dark color doesn't stick

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, keyboard, uikit

In our app, we set the keyboardAppearance to dark. This produces a black keyboard, as expected. However, if the keyboard is showing, and we press the home button, and then go back into the app, the keyboard turns white, as shown. Any ideas why?

[image: wrong colored dark keyboard]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may  have todo with the fact that the keyboard is a global object. There's only ever one keyboard in memory at any given time. Also, the OS will automatically change the keyboard color based on the background. Therefore, your setting is probably just getting overridden. I would suggest hiding the keyboard when your app enters the background, and then re-show it when it re-enters the foreground. Then when you re-show the keyboard reset the keyboard appearance via code.

Comment: Thank for your answer.
I have the same problem, But there are 2 UITextView and Two UISearchBar. But problem reproduce only with one UITextView. Do you have any ideas why it could happened?

Comment: Are you sure that you are resigning first responder from the correct object? You said you have multiple search bars and text views, so it could be possible that the item you're resigning first responder on isn't actually the first responder. However, that is just speculation as I cannot see your code and shouldn't be taken as an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! You helped me a lot!