# TvOS Keyboard lose keyboardAppearance after minimizing

Tags: cocoa, sdk, keyboard, tvos

I have an app with `UISearchContainerViewController`.

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsTableController)
searchController.searchBar.keyboardAppearance = .dark
let container = UISearchContainerViewController(searchController: searchController)
```

Then I add it to screen. The keyboard look like intended. After that i minimize the application and expand it back. The keyboard become `.light` appearance. And no way to bring it back to `.dark`. How to fix that?

Before
[image: dark appearance]

After
[image: light appearance]

Looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/28114622/5790492

Comment: It's been over a month, did you find solution to this issue?

Comment: Any luck ?? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: No solutions yet(

Comment: The only workaround I've found was to reload the `UISearchController` when the app returns to foreground. This has unfortunately other unwanted effects.

Comment: Reload or recreate.

Comment: recreate, I'm reloading contents of the VC that serves as container

Answer (score 0):

`window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark`

This line in AppDelegate fixed it for me.

Comment: Can you put some more context about your answer?